# How to make Excel send an e-mail to a specific recipient containing a specific sheet from a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need excel to pick a specific sheet from an open workbook and send it to a specific recipient at the end of each month.

Comment: see section "Mailing Single Sheets as Attachments" in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458119(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will save the open sheet to a specified path, with the sheetname as filename, then create an Outlook-Mail to a specified Receiver, and attache the newly saved Excel-sheet...

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim Anrede As String, Text1 As String, Text2 As String, path As String, sheetname As String
    path = "\\enter\your\path\here\"
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Anrede = "Dear Sir or Madam,"
    Text1 = "blablabla"
    Text2 = "Kind regards, "
    Sheets(sheetname).Copy
    ChDir path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            path & sheetname & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .To = "mail@adress.here" 'specify receiver mail here, may be a variable too
        .Subject = "Your subject here "
        .Body = Anrede & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Text1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Text2
        .Attachments.Add path & sheetname & ".xlsx"
        .Display 'Or use .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: mr @thomas Stracke thank you,,, I am trying to understand your code, there are number of terms new to me such as CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem, xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup.

Comment: yes it worked well thank you, but this procedure lacks one last thing, it does not send the mail automatically but waits for me to click send in outlook new mail window, can it send that automatically without me even feel that it is sending? cause I usually have lots of mails to send and lots of work to do and want something to reduce the process of mail sending.

Comment: Just use .Send instead of .Display and it should send it without waiting. Thanks for the "accept"! First "bonus" for me (after having answered three others without any feedback...)

Comment: You were very helpful in this,, thanks thanks very much, and if you have time sir, can I make this code execute at the end of every month?

Comment: Should not be the Problem to execute it automatically, however I'd therefore need to know which worksheet should be sent automatically. And probably it's easyer to execute it always at the very beginning of the (following) month, which would always be the first of... whereas the last day of the month is sometimes the 30th, sometimes the 31th, and sometimes the 28th/29th... Could you specify this a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir, I've written the following if statement which worked as desired: If Day(Date) = 30 Or Day(Date) = 31 Or(Month(Date) = 2 And Day(Date) = 28) then